# How to redirect two buttons on a different path with the same action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to create discount coupons subtracting total basket of my customers.
I'm not sure it's the best way to do it but I created a solution that works almost.
The only problem is that when I create coupon, I can't render the same page because my order's update method redirect to the checkout page. I want to different redirections, one for checkout when the customer click on the checkout button on my cart page, the other when the customer create a coupon on the same cart page. The two buttons uses the same update action.
Any idea how to solve it ?

Here's my orders_controller:

```
def update
  @order = current_order
  update_coupon
  if @order.update(order_params)
    redirect_to checkout_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def update_coupon
  if @order.update(:coupon => params[:order])
    redirect_to cart_path
  end
end
```

Here's my carts/show.html.erb:

```
<p>Total TTC: <%= number_to_currency @order.subtotal  %></p>
<% if @order.add_reduc.nil? %>
<% else %>
  <p style="color:green;">-<%= number_to_currency @order.add_reduc, id: "new_reduc" %></p>
#set coupon value to nil
  <%= form_for @order do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :coupon, :value => nil %>
    <%= f.submit "x" %>
  <% end %>
  <p>Price after reduction: <%= number_to_currency  @order.subtotal_with_reduc %></p>
  <p style="color:green;"><%= @order.coupon_description %></p>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :coupon, placeholder:'place your coupon' %>
  <%= f.submit "Go coupon" %>
<% end %>
```

and my order.rb :

```
COUPONS = {
  'MAREDUC' => '25% off',
  'CHOCOLOVER' => '10€ free',
  'PAPLAFUN' => '10% off'
}

def subtotal_all_inclusive
  if self.add_reduc.nil?
    subtotal + shipping
  else
    subtotal_with_reduc + shipping
  end 
end

def coupon_description
  COUPONS[coupon]
end

def add_reduc
  if self.coupon == "MAREDUC"
    subtotal * 25 / 100
  elsif self.coupon == "CHOCOLOVER" && self.subtotal >= 50
    10
  elsif self.coupon == "PAPLAFUN"
    subtotal * 10 /100
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a hidden field in the coupon form:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :from_coupon, 1  %>
  <%= f.text_field :coupon, placeholder:'place your coupon' %>
<%= f.submit "Go coupon" %>
```

And then:

```
def update
  @order = current_order
  if params[:from_coupon]
    update_coupon
  else
    if @order.update(order_params)
      redirect_to checkout_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Or you may create an additional action in routes.rb:

```
resources :orders do
  member do
    put 'update_coupon'
  end
end
```

And then:

```
<%= form_for @order, :url => update_coupon_order_path(@order), :method => :put do |f| %>
```

And then remove `private` in controller.

Answer (score 2):

Pass additional param to url and check if it present make different actions. Example

`<%= form_for @order, url: order_path(@order, additional: "your_param") do |f| %>`